# Why can't I click on my anchors when applying a jquery carousel to the code?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a slide show at the top of my page, I am using this plugin: https://github.com/thomaslanciaux/jquery-carousel/blob/master/src/jquery.carousel.js

This is the result so far: http://robert.aurelslab.co.uk/, as you can see, I can not click on the read more links. I noticed that if I remove the above carousel script, I can get the links working. To do have any idea on how I can fix this?

I have tried adding a z-index:-100; to all the relevant wrapping divs but it did not help the situation. Is there something I can do to make the "read more"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is beacause #slider has negative z-index. You should add this css:

```
#slider{
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest stable version of Chrome, when loading the page the `div` with `class="carousel-wrap"` has a `style=""` attribute with height of **136px**.  This is too small.  When I click the next or previous button on your image slider it suddenly expands to **272px** which is high enough that it works fine and the read more button is then clickable.  You have a conflicting height: attribute in your CSS somewhere, or some javascript is applying that height: attribute and you changed it in one spot but missed another spot.

Check all your heights.